# Precompiled JSP and Servlets on a Weblogic server (UNIX)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, weblogic

We have a web application hosted on this webLogic server on a UNIX machine. Its primarily a JSP/Servlet based app. Whenever we do a modification/enhancemment to any one of those JSps or servlets, I precompile them on my local and deploy them on the UNIX system. For example, if there is a file called GetIdServlet.class, we usually rename the existing file to say GetIdServlet.class1 and then put in the new file as GetIdServlet.class. This is just to be able to revert back to the original file in case they are needed.  However, I notice very strange behaviour. The application loses some functionality whenever we stop and start the server. The functionality may be  back on the next or a few restarts after that. For example, a submit button that is supposed to direct it to the next page just stops working. It may start working after a few restart.

However on my local(Eclipse + webLogic) there is absolutely no issue. Everything works fine. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: I believe you need to trim your jsp to put all of your code in one line (typically, via ANT task).

I already had a similar problem and this solution worked.

Comment: @user1106986....can you pls elaborate?? Thanks

Comment: I think you are right. I counted the no of lines in the files on my local which was around 368 line s and on the UNIX deployment, it was 352 lines. Probably that's the issue as u say.

Comment: =) Right now i don't have time to elaborate but if you still remain with the problem, i´ll elaborate my answer later

Answer (score 0):

You are using Unix Environment and i assume that the local desk setup used is windows OS or MAC. thus, when you copy the class files you are using some tool like WinSCP.

in case so, then please set the copy settings of such tool to use binary method of copying the files.

Example in WinSCP. go to Options->Preferences->Select Transfer in the Side Menu->under the Transfer Mode section, Select Binary option as the Transfer Mode. This will ensure that the binary replica is created on the Unix environment and that no data is lost in the transfer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try this and I am now able to see that the code in the JSP is the same on both my local and the server. However, still I have that issue of loss of functionality. I will try the other suggestion of minifying javascript and see.

Comment: One more thing, remove all previous class files from the server and keep a backup on your local system for the same. some times, the weblogic server is not able to lose the persistence data from the cache and is not able to update the application EAR.

Comment: I think it is a server setting issue. On my local and on another UNIX server, the app is deployed, but there are no issues there. I will update when I find a fix.